# Why do I get threat for being a ruler?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Why does "Ruler of Armenia" contribute 1% to my threat whereas the other king titles and my empire title does not? I'm not even holding the title king of Armenia anymore I gave to one of my vassals.

[image]

Comment: Is Armenia de-jure part of your primary emperor title?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are receiving 1% Threat from being the Liege of Armenia. When a vassal (such as your King of Armenia) generates Threat a portion of that Threat is also added to their liege. Odds are the King of Armenia recently won a relatively small war that expanded his territory (or inherited land, or vassalized someone).